# Copying Eclipse SASS/SCSS plugin from Aptana to Zend Studio

Tags: eclipse-plugin, zend-studio, aptana, sass

I am in desperate need of a SCSS plugin for my Zend Studio. Unfortunately Zend Studio doesn't support .scss files. And I can't find any other Eclipse plugins to help me.

I noticed that Aptana Studio 3 beta supports syntax validation and coloring of .scss files, and it works pretty good.

I located the file Aptana-3-dir/plugins/com.aptana.editor.sass_3.0.0.1287697610.jar, which must be responsible of supporting .scss files.

Is there any way to copy this feature to my Zend Studio installation?

Thanks in advance for any helpful answers.

Sebastian

Comment: SASS in Zend Studio give this a try: http://wirelesswombat.com/2012/06/17/automatically-compling-sass-compass-in-eclipse-zend-studio/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't simply copy over this single plugin and expect it to work, as it relies on a number of other aptana plugins to work properly. You might be able to install aptana as a plugin to your Zend Studio installation. Go to http://aptana.com/products/studio3/download select the Eclipse Plugin version and follow the instructions.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll give it a try when I've got time. Thanks.